# Issues with manipulating an array obtained from server with web sockets

Tags: java, node.js, websocket

I have some issues in manipulating an array obtained in the callback function in through websockets

Server side code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var startTime = currentTime - (5*60*1000);
    step = 30*1000;
    var stats = [];
    stats["values"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1];
    stats["start"] = startTime;
    stats["end"] = currentTime;

    socket.emit('initial', { stats: stats }); 
    socket.on('echo', function (data) {

    }); 
});
```

Client side code

```
var data;

socket.on('initial', function (stats) {
  data = stats.stats;
});
```

Now when I try to manipulate the data variable.Like using push and shift

```
data.values.push(10);
data.values.shift();
```

I was expecting it to have

2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1, 10

But I don't know shift operation completely removes all the elements and I get only 10 remaining in the array. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you will get your response object `{stats: stats}`, but you are interested in the `stats` property:

```
var data;

socket.on('initial', function (obj) {
  data = obj.stats;
});
```

Comment: @Irsjng. That's what I did. Sorry I mistyped it in the code. I have fixed it now. The thing is even though I do this it is not working. When I try to manipulate the data object using shift. It removes all the elements

Comment: are you sure the array was really filled before?

Comment: you init your stats as `var stats = [];` change that into `var stats = {};`

Comment: can you post a `console.log` of `data` before you manipulate it?